# Using R package in python

Tags: python, r

I'm facing issue using RCIT R package in python

I've installed the package from R CLI and importing in python using rpy2

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr('RCIT')
```

But still getting this error when I try to use it

```
model_pc = cdt.causality.graph.PC()
graph_pc = model_pc.predict(df, skeleton)

R Package (k)pcalg/RCIT is not available. RCIT has to be installed from https://github.com/Diviyan-Kalainathan/RCIT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdt/causality/graph/PC.py", line 176, in __init__
    raise ImportError("R Package (k)pcalg/RCIT is not available. "
ImportError: R Package (k)pcalg/RCIT is not available. RCIT has to be installed from https://github.com/Diviyan-Kalainathan/RCIT
```